# What can cause that localStorage is null? (Chrome/Android)

Tags: javascript, android, local-storage

I see in error tracking software that 0.25% of users hit this issue. The only pattern I can see is Android 6.0.1/5.1.1 and Chrome 54 or 55. What can cause that localStorage is null? It's a web app (not wrapped in WebView) and when you disable possibility to set users data it actually throws an exception when you try to access it and not sets it to null.

Cheers!

Comment: Explanation and possible solution: https://michalzalecki.com/why-using-localStorage-directly-is-a-bad-idea/

Comment: I cannot find any explanation of why `localStorage` would be null in that article. If you've found one, would you mind summarizing it and posting it as an answer here?

Comment: On chrome desktop I found that when I block cookies for a certain site, it also causes `localStorage` to be `null`. I could not block *only cookies*.

Comment: Are we sure it's the `localStorage` that's null or some value of it?